# Como Implementar "zoom in" e "zoom out" para imageView no Android?

Tags: android, imageview

Tenho uma activity onde exibo uma imagem no tamanho da tela, porém eu precisava implementar o zoom na imagem, zoom igual ao do sistema Android que tem em todas as galerias e nos navegadores do Android. Alguém sabe como fazer ou que biblioteca implementar? Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1):

Esta classe customizada parece fazer o que você quer:

https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom

Tem algumas idéias sobre como implementar ampliação do zero,  neste post em inglês:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out

As formas básicas são:

1) mudar o "bounds", ou seja, o retângulo no qual a ImageView é desenhada. Especificando um "bounds" bem grande, a imagem será desenhada ampliada. Ela *não* tomará a tela toda se a ImageView estiver dentro de outra View com tamanho limitado (a parte visível da imagem é o "bounds" da view que contém). No iOS o truque equivalente funciona muito bem (no iOS, não é "bounds", é "frame").

2) usar uma transformada, através de setImageMatrix(). Talvez seja a melhor forma porque permite muitas alterações na imagem (virar, entortar, deslocar, ampliar...) A vantagem é que esse método setImageMatrix() é específico do ImageView, e atua diretamente sobre a imagem, o "bounds" da View não precisa ser mexido e é respeitado (a imagem não vai transbordar para a tela toda se for ampliada, por exemplo, e não é preciso outro view que contenha a ImageView para "clipar", como seria necessário no método 1).